# ng-repeat orderBy keeping fixed top value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-orderby

see the fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/prantikv/gcz4gwgw/1/

i want to get one i item on the top of the list and the rest in alphabetical order:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
 <ul>
  <li ng-repeat="value in name | orderBy:'name'">{{value.name}} </li>   
   </ul>    

  </div>
```

In my controller i have the following

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.name=[
{name:'zani',country:'Norway'},
{name:'aege',country:'Sweden'},
{name:'Kai',country:'Denmark'}]


}
```

what i want is the name "kai" to come first and then the rest in alphabetical order.

================Edit===============

now i have played and got the following

in my view:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
 <ul>
  <li ng-repeat="value in name | orderBy:myValueFunction ">{{value.name}} </li>   
   </ul>    

  </div>
```

in my controller :

```
 $scope.myValueFunction = function(value) {
    if(value.name == "kai"){

        return value.name;
    }else{
        //what todo here so the rest of the list is sorted alphabetically
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Above answer is good to implement but as you don't have an option to edit a response then you follow easy workaround like I mentioned below. Else you could go for creating custom filter.

**Markup**

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="single in name | filter:{'name':'Kai'}">{{single.name}} </li>  
    <li ng-repeat="value in name | filter:{'name':'!Kai'}" | orderBy:'name'">{{value.name}} </li>   
  </ul>    
</div>
```

Comment: looks good but will it cause the app to lag if the list is big?

Comment: @krv big in the the sense? what would be the big number exactly?

Comment: i edited the code now the item that i want appears on top but the rest of the list is not sorted..

Answer (score 7):

You can add a "pinned" variable to your array item, and make it like this:

```
$scope.name=[
{name:'zani',country:'Norway', pinned: false},
{name:'aege',country:'Sweden', pinned: false},
{name:'Kai',country:'Denmark', pinned: true}]
```

And then change you ng-repeat accordingly:

```
<li ng-repeat="value in name | orderBy:['pinned','name']">{{value.name}} </li>
```

Now as "pinned" has the first order priority, 'kai' will always be the first in the loop.

Comment: i am getting the data form a database so it will be hard to do so..isn't there any other custom function that i can use?

Comment: You can create a custom angular filter that handles the sorting. Then you could just use: <li ng-repeat="keyword in keywords|my_sort"> {{ whatever}} </li> 
but I would say that is harder. I think in your angular code when you fetch the data, just write a loop that adds the "pinned" variable to every item. Really doesn't look so hard.

Comment: Since this is javascript you don't even need to include pinned:false on the other objects, a attribute not present counts as false.

Answer (score 3):

for those coming to this question i got it to work:
Working fiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/prantikv/gcz4gwgw/7/

so in my view i have the following:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
 <ul>
  <li ng-repeat="value in name | orderBy:myValueFunction ">{{value.name}} </li>   
   </ul>    

  </div>
```

in my controller:

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
$scope.name=[
    {name:'zani',country:'Norway'},
    {name:'aege',country:'Sweden'},
    {name:'Kai',country:'Denmark'}];

   $scope.myValueFunction = function(value) {

    if(value.name == "Kai"){
            return -1; //skip this sort and place at top
    }else{
        return value.name;//return the default sort
    }
   }  
 }
```

This works with alphabetical sort as it is the default sort order